# How can I keep the top bar stationary in Jetpack Compose when the keyboard is displayed?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I'm encountering an issue with the layout behavior in a chat screen using Jetpack Compose. I have a Scaffold containing a TopAppBar, a BottomBar with a TextField, and a LazyColumn between them for the chat content. When the keyboard pops up after clicking on the TextField in the BottomBar, the entire screen, including the TopAppBar, shifts up. I'm aiming for a behavior similar to messaging apps like WhatsApp, where the TopAppBar remains fixed while only the BottomBar and the LazyColumn (chat content) move with the keyboard.

Here's a snippet of my current code:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        
    },
    bottomBar = {
        // CustomNavBar (BottomBar) implementation containing a TextField for typing messages
    }
) { paddingValues ->
    // Box containing the content of the chat screen (LazyColumn)
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(
            top = paddingValues.calculateTopPadding(),
            bottom = paddingValues.calculateBottomPadding()
        )
    ) {
        // Chat content (OneToOneChatScreen or GroupChatScreen) displayed within LazyColumn
    }
}
```

I also have the problem with the bottomBar that there remains gap between DropDownItems and Row which has TextField, when my DropDownMenu is expanded.
My customBottomBar

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun CustomNavBar(
    allSendersContactMethods: List<String>
) {
    var messageText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val showSendButton: Boolean by remember { derivedStateOf { messageText.isNotEmpty() } }
    var sendersContactMethodNumber: Int by remember { mutableIntStateOf(1) }
    var expanded: Boolean by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedSendersContactMethod by remember { mutableStateOf(allSendersContactMethods.first()) }


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
    ) {
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()

        ) {
            allSendersContactMethods.forEachIndexed { index, method ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        sendersContactMethodNumber = index + 1
                        selectedSendersContactMethod = method
                        expanded = false
                    },
                    text = {
                        Text(text = method)
                    },
                )
            }
        }

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 4.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            TextField(
                value = messageText,
                onValueChange = { messageText = it },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .weight(1f)
                    .background(
                        shape = CircleShape,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseOnSurface
                    )
                    .padding(horizontal = 8.dp),
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Type a message") },
                maxLines = 4,
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    containerColor = Color.Transparent
                ),
                trailingIcon = {

                    Row(
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
                    ) {

                        Text(
                            text = "$sendersContactMethodNumber",
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .clickable { expanded = true }
                                .border(
                                    1.5.dp, MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                                    RoundedCornerShape(4.dp)
                                )
                                .padding(vertical = 1.dp, horizontal = 4.dp)
                        )

                        if (showSendButton) {
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(4.dp))
                            IconButton(onClick = { /* Handle send action */ }) {
                                Icon(
                                    Icons.Outlined.Send,
                                    contentDescription = "Send",
                                    tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to add ```TopAppBar``` into the ```Column``` rather adding into the ```Scaffold```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer. Just have to add **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>** in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

it's better to add your TopAppBar into the Column like this:

```
Column {
            // Top bar
            TopAppBar(
                title = {
                    // Your title content here
                },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primarySurface)
            )
        }
```

also you can find the visibility of keyboard to customize your view.
you can fine visibility by this code:

```
    var isKeyboardVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    keyboardController?.let {
    DisposableEffect(keyboardController) {
    val callback = {
        isKeyboardVisible = it.isVisible
        }
        it.addVisibilityChangeListener(callback)
        onDispose {
            it.removeVisibilityChangeListener(callback)
            }
        }
    }
```

and now you can customize your view like this:

```
 Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1f)
        .padding(
            top = if (isKeyboardVisible) 0.dp 
else 
    LocalDensity.current.density.toDp(),
            bottom = if (isKeyboardVisible) 0.dp 
else 
    LocalDensity.current.density.toDp()
        )
)
```

Comment: it is showing me error in all the below lines:"it.isVisible
        }
        it.addVisibilityChangeListener(callback)
        onDispose {
            it.removeVisibilityChangeListener(callback)
            }
        }"

Comment: Unresolved reference: isVisible, Unresolved reference: addVisibilityChangeListener, Unresolved reference: removeVisibilityChangeListener